# Module parse failed getting error in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I am working on webpack in react, when i run this command `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js` , i am getting below error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

here i have attached my `webpack.config.js` , can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ?

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                "targets": "defaults" 
              }],
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please attach the content of your `webpack.config.js` file

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install `style-loader` and `css-loader`:

```sh
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

Then add the loaders to your webpack config. For example:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                "targets": "defaults" 
              }],
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check my webpack.config.js, i have updated in my question

Comment: Try adding the rule above in your webpack config. Updated my example to match your webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`"babel": { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }`

To the end of your package.json file - after devDependencies (you may need to add @babel/preset-env via Yarn as well.)